# font-awesome and images is not loaded in ruby-on-rails-4 production firefox

Tags: firefox, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using font-awesome in ruby-on-rails-4 and in my development mode everything works fine
in both chrome and firefox. But i am not able to find out what is the reason that font-awesome and images is not loaded into production mode, where font-awesome is works fine in chrome.

Comment: Have you precompiled static assets ?

Comment: yes, i precompile assets and it works fine in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for font-awesome in rails 4:

https://coderwall.com/p/1uqvkq

Hope it will help.

Or 
Try this if above one not working for you.
first: add `app/assets/fonts` to the asset path (config/application.rb)

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

then move the font files into /assets/fonts (create the folder first)

Now rename the font-awesome.css to font-awesome.css.scss.erb and edit it like this: change:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')    format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

to this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.eot") %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.eot") + "?#iefix" %>') format('eot'), url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.woff") %>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf") %>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.svg") + "#FontAwesome" %>') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Lets try this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.

As it turns out it was due to the fact that I was compiling assets in staging mode and running in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for me was to use the CDN described on the [Font Awesome "get started" page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/).

Delete any local copy of the stylesheet and font files, and just put this in the head:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

(current as of 07-07-2014, see link above for most recent release)